# Is the Gravitational Constant $G$ really a Constant?

Tags: energy, gravity, physical-constants

I'm a mere chemist, so I'm figuratively typing and ducking, as I ask this, but:-

If Dark Energy is increasing, then could this not be explained by the Gravitational Constant $G$ not being constant, but actually a value which could be decreasing.

Or, perhaps the $G$ Constant Changed, at @ 6 billion years ago when Dark Energy increased in value.
Perhaps at 6 billion years ago the density / temperature, of the Universe, was the point at which the Universe went through a Phase Transition, as do Superconductors at a molecular / atomic level?

Comment: Nope. It's safe to say that we thought of this. I mean, you have to assume that the scientists spending their whole life on the issue are going to think of the same things at least as another scientist spending 5 minutes on it.

Comment: It *could be,* but it entirely depends on what *model* of dark energy you're working with?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21721/2451 and links therein.