# How do we know that the speed of light is constant everywhere, not just here?

Tags: speed-of-light, curvature, physical-constants

It might well be that universal constants, say the speed of light, are only constant as far as we can tell in our chunk of the universe - in the same way that the Earth looks flat in the area you live.

Are there any ways to tell that the speed of light is actually the same not just in our "neighbourhood" but in all the observable universe?

Comment: We don't know. But it's a postulate that works without any issues so far. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light

Comment: A different speed of light would impact physics pretty generally. Things like the energy levels in atoms contain it…

Comment: It's impossible to conduct every necessary experiment at every point in space and every moment in time, and therefore it is a necessary postulate of physics that the laws of physics hold invariant of space and time. Otherwise, physics could only be claimed to work subjectively and would need to be verified and inductively reasoned by every observer in order for that observer to use it, which is of course beyond unreasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proof that the universal constants ($G$, $\hbar$, $\ldots$) are really constant in time and space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21721/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the attitude of most working scientists would be that we should make the most conservative possible assumptions when extrapolating the laws of physics to new areas, and see how far you can get. If you run into a contradiction, then this is evidence that we need to revise our underlying assumptions. However, if a consistent picture emerges, this is evidence that the underlying assumptions work and can be used to build a coherent story.

In particular, the simplest assumption is to assume that the speed of light is constant. This assumption (plus the framework of general relativity) allows us to build a picture of cosmology and astrophysics that is remarkably consistent. As an example of what I mean by "consistent", multiple independent probes of the history of the Universe, such as measurements of the abundance of primordial elements as well as measurements of the cosmic microwave background, can be used to estimate the number of neutrinos, and both come up with an answer consistent with three to within error bars, which is consistent with the Standard Model of particle physics. Many such internal consistency checks have been done, and point to the basic framework with conservative assumptions being correct (or at least, approxiimately correct).

Now, there is a small discrepancy (the now infamous "Hubble tension"), and as a result there is a lot of work understanding which of our many assumptions might be leading to a contradiction. It could well be that there is some exotic new physics, like a changing speed of light, that could explain it (although as far as I know, there isn't an actual concrete theory with a changing speed of light that has been proposed to solve this problem; I am just illustrating the logic of how scientists think). Or, it could be that there is some subtle technical issue with, say, how the distance ladder is calibrated, that leads to a biased estimate of the Hubble constant by one team or another.

From the other end, people also have also imagined what it would look like if the speed of light were not constant. You can then look for (presumably small) experimental signatures consistent with a theory that has this property. As a technical point, since the speed of light is a dimensionful parameter, it is not actually meaningful to ask if its value changes -- we can always choose our units so it has any value we want. However, there is a dimensionless quantity -- the fine structure constant $\alpha$ -- in which the speed of light appears. So we can ask what happens if the fine structure constant changes with spacetime. This would have many effects, such as changing the sizes and energy levels of atoms. This kind of effect is well constrained by measurements of various spectral lines, and therefore there is a tight constraint on how much $\alpha$ can vary. In the lab, constraints are very tight; according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Potential_time-variation) $\frac{\dot \alpha}{\alpha}\lesssim 10^{-17} {\rm\ per\ year}$. Using astrophysical measurements to consider time variation of $\alpha$ in the past seems to be more controversial, but different methods seem to agree at least with a bound of $\frac{\dot \alpha}{\alpha}\lesssim 10^{-5} {\rm\ per\ 10\ billion\ years}$.

Answer (score 0):

The "observable universe" is a relic. It is a combination of images we receive that tell us how the universe was at those points light was emitted from at the time it was emitted. It is, of course, an ever-changing picture. The light we receive from our Sun takes minutes to get here. Light from nearby stars takes a few years.

There's a lot going on in our picture of the universe but the vast majority of it is vacuum (empty space). In our "neighbourhood," we measure light moving at constant speed in a vacuum. Water slows it down and glass slows it down but just as light unfailingly reaches us from the Sun, we have little reason to suspect that the light emitted by distant stars is not behaving the same way.

To take local measurements in all the distant places we've seen, we'd need to go there, but they've all moved on because of space expansion and some are so far away now that even if we could travel at the speed of light, we'd never reach them. Plus, a lot of the stars will have burnt out.

Also: Consider that those neighbourhoods mightn't be as nice as ours. The aliens there could trick us by making light appear to move at different speeds. We need to be careful.

Comment: Do we actually measure constant speed of light astronomically? I would think we calculate things using theory that postulates a constant speed of light, and see good agreement with observables.

Comment: @RC_23 Yes, you have a better way of putting it.

Answer (score 0):

For an answer, you must first decide on what sort of experiment you consider definitive. Speed is distance/time, so what's your ruler and what's your clock? Our current definitions of the meter and second are both based on the same atomic oscillation: the speed of light is thus fixed by definition.

This doesn't mean that some other definition(s) can't lead to a variable speed of light, but what do you suggest? What does "the speed of light" mean to you?